# Upgrading Debian - Error processing manpages

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy

I'm upgrading from Debian 7 (Wheezy) to 9 (Stretch).

I've tried:

```
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

I'm getting an error as it's trying to unpack the manpages it looks like.

Output:

```
After this operation, 585 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch/main manpages all 4.10-2 [1,222 kB]
Fetched 1,222 kB in 0s (2,055 kB/s)
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 187746 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace manpages 3.44-1 (using .../manpages_4.10-2_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement manpages ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/manpages_4.10-2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/iconv.1.gz', which is also in package libc-bin 2.13-38+deb7u12
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/manpages_4.10-2_all.deb
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libapt-inst
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libapt-pkg
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libespeak-dev
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libespeak1
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libgpgme11-dev
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package kodi-api-guilib
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package kodi-api-pvr
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libparse-cpan-meta-perl
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libjpeg62
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package lsb
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package lsb-core
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-log-implementation
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-seclib
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-sabre-http
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-math-biginteger
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pkg-config
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package sagenb-export
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package sagenb-export
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried to force it:

dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/manpages_4.10-2_all.deb

```
(Reading database ... 187746 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace manpages 3.44-1 (using .../manpages_4.10-2_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement manpages ...
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/iconv.1.gz', which is also in package libc-bin 2.13-38+deb7u12
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/ldd.1.gz', which is also in package libc-bin 2.13-38+deb7u12
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/locale.1.gz', which is also in package libc-bin 2.13-38+deb7u12
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/localedef.1.gz', which is also in package libc-bin 2.13-38+deb7u12
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/mtrace.1.gz', which is also in package libc-dev-bin 2.13-38+deb7u12
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/sprof.1.gz', which is also in package libc-dev-bin 2.13-38+deb7u12
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man5/gai.conf.5.gz', which is also in package libc-bin 2.13-38+deb7u12
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/iconvconfig.8.gz', which is also in package libc-bin 2.13-38+deb7u12
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/ld.so.8.gz', which is also in package libc-bin 2.13-38+deb7u12
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/ldconfig.8.gz', which is also in package libc-bin 2.13-38+deb7u12
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/zic.8.gz', which is also in package libc-bin 2.13-38+deb7u12
Setting up manpages (4.10-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian doesn't support upgrading from one suite to another, which is not the direct "follow-up".

Regarding your specific situation: You need to upgrade to `jessie` first, and after this to `stretch`.

Comment: I should have known better.  You're right.  Thank you.

Comment: @MattWiner I hope the procedure worked in the end. Glad this answer helped! All the best..